# Bug in copying and sorting array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

This is the original question

Create a Method `int[] sort(int[] arr)`, returning a new sorted array (increasing order), containing the same set of integers as arr. Array arr should be left unchanged.

This is the method:

```
private static int[] sort(int[] arr){
        int i,z=0,temp,y,x;
        int[] secondArray = new int [arr.length];
        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            secondArray[z] = arr[i];
        }
        for (y=0; y < secondArray.length; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x<secondArray.length; x++){
                if (secondArray[y] < secondArray[x]){
                    temp = secondArray[y];
                    secondArray[y] = secondArray[x];
                    secondArray[x] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return secondArray;
    }
```

input  :  `int[] n = {1,4,5,343,45,67};`

output : `1 4 5 343 45 67`

It is easy to sort array arr, but the question requires to left arr unchanged. So I tried to create a new array, and sort the new one, but it doesn't work.

Plese help.

Comment: do you have to sort it manually?

Comment: Carefully re-read the loop that copies the array.

Comment: This algoritm can't be use with a parallel array, you could copy the array first or use an other algorith.

Comment: One tip: Don’t declare your local variables until you need them. As far as I can see, this simple practice should catch the bug in your code. And in addition make for more readable code.

Comment: Also I suspect that you don’t need the varable `z` at all (it’s 0 all the way through the method, never changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to sort the array manually:

```
private static int[] sort(int[] arr){
    int[] secondArray = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        secondArray[i] = arr[i];
    }

    return Arrays.sort(secondArray);
}
```

Comment: The answer is obvious but I uess that this is training exercice to use loops and array. _This is the original question_

Comment: Yes, I'm just not a fan of doing peoples homework :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. You can always choose some different method for sorting arrays.
Bubblesort which you use is one of easiest but not the best. 
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html

```
    int[] old = {1,4,5,343,45,67};
    int[] newOne = Arrays.copyOf(old, old.length);//copy array
    Arrays.sort(newOne);//sort

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(old));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newOne));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] sort(int[] arr){
    return IntStream.of(arr).sorted().toArray();
}
```